# orderByChild() doesn't seem to be ordering my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the list of items. The limitToLast(10) works fine but everything is clearly out of order. I've tried it with several different child keys with same result.

```
function _listAll() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var claims = [];
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseurl + '/Claims').orderByChild('Status').limitToLast(10);
    ref.on("value", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(child){
            angular.forEach(child.val(), function(value, key){
                claims.push(value)
            })
        });
        deferred.resolve(claims);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I don't have access to the firebase for this data but I logged the data for the first claim so you can see the structure:

[image: Data]

Comment: it's not clear from what you've shown what order you expect or whether the data is out of order.

Comment: I'm using orderByChild('Status') so am expecting this to be ordered alphabetically by the Status. 

I didn't think it made sense to include all 10 of the data entries just to show that its out of order but if it helps here is a screen shot of the data out of order http://imgur.com/ZjyLVcF

Comment: You should be looking at the data inside the firebase foreach call - that guarantees the order. Inspecting the data object itself doesn't work and I don't know whether whatever you're doing with angular messes up the ordering afterwards. To verify you're getting ordered data, log it first thing in the data.forEach call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction that definitely helped. So it looks like  the data is structured a layer deeper than I thought. First there is the list of claims by ID. Within that object is what appears to be a randomly generated number and then finally within that object is the desired object that I want to filter on. That is why whoever was working on this code before me implemented the angular.forEach which just peeled back that extra layer essentially. Is there a way to order by the child of a child? Even so, not sure how to get to that second child.

Comment: That seems like a different question entirely. You should write up an MVCE for it, as it is, it's hard to really tell what's going on in your code without any ability to run it. You might sort it out yourself by writing the MVCE to begin with, especially if you force yourself to temporarily toss the angular dependency.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a bunch for your help